# How to pass decreasing and/or na.last argument to sort through tapply in R

Tags: r, sorting, vector, tapply

I am teaching myself the basics of R and have been encountering trouble using the function *tapply* when passing the *sort* function while trying to use non-default optional arguments for sort. Here is an example of the trouble I am facing:

Given the vectors

```
x <- c(1.1, 1.0, 2.1, NA_real_)
y <- c("a", "b", "c","d")
```

I find that

```
tapply(y, x, sort, decreasing=TRUE, na.last=TRUE)
```

results in the same output regardless of the logical assignments I endow decreasing and na.last with. In fact, the output always defaults to the sort default values

```
decreasing = FALSE, na.last = NA
```

For the record, when inputing the above example, the output is

```
> tapply(y, x, sort, decreasing=TRUE, na.last=TRUE)
  1 1.1 2.1
"b" "a" "c"
```

Let me also mention that if I define the alternate function

```
sort2 <- function(v) sort(v, decreasing=TRUE, na.last=TRUE);
```

and pass *sort2* to *tapply* instead, I still encounter the same trouble.

I am using running this code on a Mac OS X 10.10.4, using R 3.2.0. Using *sort* standalone results in the desired behavior (calling *sort* on its own without passing through *tapply*, that is), since it acts appropriately when altering the *decreasing* and *na.last* arguments.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Comment: what output are you expecting?  You are splitting `y` by `x` and sorting each component, whcih consists of single values.  Try `x <- c(1.1, 1.0, 2.1, NA_real_); y <- c("a", "a", "d","d"); tapply(x, y, sort, decreasing=TRUE, na.last=TRUE)`

Comment: @nongkrong What I had hoped for was that by passing different values for decreasing, I could have this result in the orderings 1, 1.1, 2.1 (when decreasing=F) and 2.1, 1.1, 1 (when decreasing=T) with the corresponding letter assignments correctly adjusted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you're using `tapply()` correctly.

```
tapply(y, x, sort, decreasing=TRUE, na.last=TRUE)
```

The above line of code basically says "sort vector `y` grouping by categorical vector `x`". Your vector `x` is not really a categorical vector at all, it's a numeric vector with only distinct values, plus an NA. `tapply()` ignores the NA index, and then treats each of the remaining three distinct numeric values in `x` as separate groups, so it passes each of the three corresponding character strings from `y` to three different calls of `sort()`, which obviously has no effect on anything (which explains why your customization arguments have no effect) and returns the result ordered by the `x` groups.

Here's an example of how to do what I think you're trying to do:

```
x <- c(NA,1,2,3,NA,2,1,3);
g <- rep(letters[1:2],each=4);
x;
## [1] NA  1  2  3 NA  2  1  3
g;
## [1] "a" "a" "a" "a" "b" "b" "b" "b"
tapply(x,g,sort,decreasing=T,na.last=T);
## $a
## [1]  3  2  1 NA
##
## $b
## [1]  3  2  1 NA
##
```

---

**Edit:** When you want to sort a vector by another vector, you can use `order()`:

```
y[order(x,decreasing=T,na.last=T)];
## [1] "c" "a" "b" "d"
y[order(x,decreasing=F,na.last=T)];
## [1] "b" "a" "c" "d"
```

Comment: Concerning your example, my hope was that by adjusting `decreasing`, the letters in `y` would either be ordered as `b a c` (as they are with `decreasing=F`), or as `c a b` (if `decreasing=T` had worked as I hoped). However, I really did want to try to use `tapply` to order the character vector `y` using the orderings of the numeric vector `x`. Anyway, thanks again. Your explanation cleared up much of my misconception of the implementation of `tapply`.

Comment: I appreciate your edit! Actually, I had the ordering implementation you describe in the edit running beforehand. The use of `tapply` was purely for pedagogy (hoping to find alternate methods to yield the same result), since I am trying to get the nuts and bolts down. Very much appreciated.